# using CNN for classification for cancer prediction

Tags: conv-neural-network, classification, conv1d

I have a dataset (CVS) with 1000 samples and 12 features. I want to use CNN for its binary classification. all the examples that I find are related to images or time series and I don't know how to describe input and layer for this purpose. Is anyone has any example?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this really helpful link. it's the classification of iris dataset which convolutional neuron network.
https://www.datatechnotes.com/2020/02/classification-example-with-keras-cnn.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).